# Preloader not transitioning in main page

Tags: javascript

I am learning how to develop websites and in my 'script.js' file, I wrote a code for a preloader but it's not working. It was working 3-4 days ago but not now. It shows a ESLint Error (Parsing error: Unexpected Token). My preloader keeps running and not transition into main page. Please help me.

```
$('window').on('load', function() {
    $('#status').fadeOut();
    $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut();
});
```

I expect the preloader to fadeOut in 350 m/s and transition into the main page.

Comment: do u have other js in ur file ?

Comment: error refers to something else, which line / column does it say the error is located?

Answer (score 0):

replace **$('window')** to **$(window)** Or **$(document)**

and if still not working try to use it like this **$(window).load** instead of **.on('load')**

Answer (score 0):

remove the `'` from window
try below code

```
$( window ).on("load", function() {
    $('#status').fadeOut();
    $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut();
});
```

Hope its help